# Execution count of installed applications

Tags: java, android

I am interested in getting values of already installed packages in android. I am trying to find the value how many times were the already installed packages executed (closed and open). I am aware i can do that for my application from sharepreferences but how to do for packages that are already there? I already have the list of the packages installed using PackageManager.

Thanks in advance

Comment: can the person that down voted my question please explain to me why they did not considered this a valid question?

Answer (score 2):

The PackageInfo class, which can be retrieved for Packages using the PackageManager can you give you information about first install time and last update time. But there doesn't seem to be any way to find out how many times it was launched, etc. I'm not even sure the system keeps track of that information. Check out http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInfo.html

Answer (score 2):

```
Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
PackageManager packageManager = mContext.getPackageManager(); 
List<ResolveInfo> apps = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(mainIntent, 0);
```

try this.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think this is possible from regular applications. Though if you have root access you can execute

```
dumpsys usagestats
```

and parse the output.

Or you could use the `Usagestats Service` that already does the tracking. But again you need root access for this.

Answer (score 0):

```
         PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();

                Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
                mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

                final List<ResolveInfo> apps = manager.queryIntentActivities(mainIntent, 0);
                Collections.sort(apps, new ResolveInfo.DisplayNameComparator(manager));

                if (apps != null) {
                    final int count = apps.size();

                    if (mApplications == null) {
                        mApplications = new ArrayList<ApplicationInfo>(count);
                    }
    }
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                  ApplicationInfo application = new ApplicationInfo();
                ResolveInfo info = apps.get(DEFAULT_KEYS_SEARCH_LOCAL);

                application.title = info.loadLabel(manager);
                application.setActivity(new ComponentName(
                        info.activityInfo.applicationInfo.packageName,
                        info.activityInfo.name),
                        Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                        | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);
                application.icon = info.activityInfo.loadIcon(manager);

              //  mApplications.add(application);

        }
```

this will give u the count of the all applications installed